# Using 80x86 Register as Array Index

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, x86

I've been trying to figure this out for a while.  In the program I'm working with, as an example, I'm taking keyboard input using:

```
MOV AH,2h;
INT 21h;
```

Basically, after that returns a character from the console, I'm trying to feed that value into an a MOV with AL as an array index, like:

```
MOV dl,array[[AL]]
```

In my simple example, I'm pulling an ASCII value and spitting back out the next character up based on a table I generated (Basically just an arbitrary exercise).

I've tried array[AL], array[[AL]], and probably a dozen other things.  When I assemble my code in MASM, I get this error:

```
**error A2031: Must be index or base register**
```

Does [AL] not return the value stored in the AL register/pointer?

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use an index or base register inside the `[]`.  In 8086 mode, the only two base registers are BX and BP, while the only two index registers are SI and DI.  So you need to do something like:

```
mov BH,0;
mov BL,AL
mov DL,array[BX];
```

rather than trying to use AL directly as a base register.  Alternately, you can try to use the XLAT instruction, which is roughly equivalent to `mov AL,[BX+AL]`

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks.  That worked.  Didn't know about the XLAT instruction, which is kind of cool.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you need to use an index register such as SI, DI, or base register BX. If I remember correctly, using other registers here requires 386 mode.
Additionally, when using as an index, remember that you may have to adjust for the size of an array element if these are not bytes (though you are probably using bytes in this case).

Index syntax should be `array[...]` I guess but it's been over 5 years since I last wrote something in assembly.

One more thing: Shouldn't AH be 01h ?
http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah01

Comment: I've been using 8 because it doesn't echo.  I guess the idea is type one thing, get another.